# GUI for management beans of Spring application

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-bean, spring2.x

Good day everyone,

During my work I often have to run an overweight Spring application to generate some content. It took a lot of time just to load data in the memory and generate some predefined content. And if I need generate some other content I have to change some bean configuration and rerun all application starting with in memory loading.

I wonder is there a some GUI library/application that could help me run my application once and give me chance to manage and run my beans on the fly? Maybe some of you had experience of management Spring Beans via Java Swing that you could share with community?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this from scratch I'd hold configuration in a Spring Cloud config server and then have beans with a scope of @RefreshScope.

As far as a GUI is concerned the config server stores the configuration in GIT so just use your favourite GIT client.

See the [documentation here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope).